# How to redirect to Template View EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

This is the Tree of my project:

```
js
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── adapters
│   │   ├── controllers
│   │   │   ├── IndexController.js
│   │   │   └── SoapClient.js
│   │   ├── img
│   │   │   └── logo.png
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── models
│   │   ├── routes
│   │   ├── serializers
│   │   ├── transforms
│   │   └── views
|   |        └── home.html
│   ├── app.js
```

Im' working with EmberJS and I wanna render a template inside of views directory, it mean I have the following controller:

```js
  App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  pin: '',
  fail: true,
  actions:
  {
    login:function()
    {

        var soapClient = SoapClient.create({url:webServiceURL, message:soapMessage });
        var result = soapClient.callService();
        var acceso =  $(result).find( 'return' ).text();

        if( acceso=='allow'){
            //this.transitionToRoute('home');
           //I wanna render a views/home.html and sed a parameter, how?
        }
        else{
            this.set('fail', false);

        }   
    }
}
});
```

Comment: No I know the framework and me is like symfony, and I realize this is a bit cumbersome to put all views on the index (for now that's how I know), then just tried to tell controllador should render the view xxx  with yyy parameters, I do not know if you can?

Comment: A failing bin would help. From what I understand, you just create view and specify the templateName (views/home) property. You can then use view.appendTo(containerSelectorName) to append the view to the dom.